# Connect to server on PC's network from android emulator

Tags: android, networking, android-emulator

I'm designing an android app that communicates with  a web server. Till now i was hosting the server on my localhost and was accessing it with `10.0.2.2` on the emulator. Now I need to access a server hosted on the company's network PC `vserver36` with address `192.168.1.124`. How do I do this on the emulator?

Comment: use 192.168.1.124 in place of 10.0.2.2, but your PC and your server PC must be in same intranet.

Comment: @SunitKumarGupta Yeah, I just tried that it worked, thanks, I thought it wouldn't becuase the emulator isn't on the PC's network

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have just to use the address 192.168.1.124 instead of 10.0.2.2 ;)

Comment: Yes I realised, but how come the emulator can connect to my PC's network??

Comment: @Kartik_Koro : The emulator can connect to any network. It's only 'localhost' which is the main problem. The use of 'localhost' on the emulator is literally the 127.0.0.1 address of the emulator itself - that's why you need to use 10.0.2.2 to access the PC's 'localhost', i.e., it is translated / routed out to the PC. Other than that, all external IP addresses are valid as long as the PC can route / connect to them. Think about it - open the browser on the emulator and type in www.google.com.